# SCJP Threads sleep method()

Tags: java, static-methods, thread-sleep

I am reading SCJP. While reading Threads , i read about `sleep()` method. But this phrase , i am not getting it. Please help me

"Remember that sleep() is a static method, so don't be fooled into thinking that
one thread can put another thread to sleep."

Some methods may look like they tell another thread to block, but they don't. If you have a reference "`t`" to another thread, you can write something like this:
`t.sleep()` , `t.yield()`
But those are actually `static` methods of the `Thread` class—they don't affect the instance `t`; instead they are defined to always affect the thread that's currently executing

Comment: Not actually related to threads. Thats the generic difference between a static method and an instance method that you should research to understand that phrase.

Answer (score 1):

That says, even though, you can call those [`yield()`, s`leep()`] methods on `Thread` instances, those instance won't be affected, because `sleep()` method is a static method. Whatever the current executing thread only will be affected, not the instance on which you invoke the `sleep()` method

[Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) says

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep

You may this, since you invoke the methods on instances and make them to sleep, but it's not

Comment: so did you mean when i have non-static methods , and i call them through object reference variable it affects the variable ? ? ? if so , how ? can you provide me any example

Comment: @user2985842 : It's depend on the method, whether it affects or not the calling instance.

Answer (score 0):

When calling static method, the instance on that it is called has no effect, be it `Thread.sleep` or say `String.valueOf`. For instance, you can write `String.valueOf(17)` but you can also write `"123".valueOf(17)` - looks weird but the result it will be "17" in both cases, without taking any consideration to "123" for the second case.

Same way, `Thread.sleep()` is a static method that always put the *current* thread to sleep, the thread from where this method is called. It is not possible to control any other thread through this method, even if for the programmer who does not understand [static methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) this may appear possible.